# Sort XML output PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

I have this XML link [XML OUTPUT](http://kopen.marktplaats.nl/opensearch.php?s=100&q=volkswagen%20or%20nissan%20or%20audi%20or%20seat%20or%20kia%20or%20toyota%20or%20peugeot%20or%20volvo%20or%20bmw%20or%20chrysler%20or%20mini%20or%20citroen%20or%20hyundai%20or%20mercedes%20or%20mazda%20or%20alfa%20or%20jeep%20or%20daewoo%20or%20honda%20or%20jaguar%20or%20mitsubishi%20or%20rover%20or%20saab%20or%20skoda%20or%20suzuki%20or%20smart&g=91).
In case the link is dead, this is the output:

```
<channel>
<title>
Marktplaats.nl - Gevonden resultaten met de zoekterm 'volkswagen or nissan or audi or seat or kia or toyota or peugeot or volvo or bmw or chrysler or mini or citroen or hyundai or mercedes or mazda or alfa or jeep or daewoo or honda or jaguar or mitsubishi or rover or saab or skoda or suzuki or smart'
</title>
<link>http://www.marktplaats.nl</link>
<description>
Marktplaats.nl - Gevonden resultaten met de zoekterm 'volkswagen or nissan or audi or seat or kia or toyota or peugeot or volvo or bmw or chrysler or mini or citroen or hyundai or mercedes or mazda or alfa or jeep or daewoo or honda or jaguar or mitsubishi or rover or saab or skoda or suzuki or smart'. Kopen en verkopen van tweedehands of nieuwe producten en van diensten doet u op Marktplaats.nl, de advertentiesite van Nederland. Marktplaats.nl is een compleet overzicht van vraag en aanbod.
</description>
<language>nl</language>
<copyright>
Copyright (C) 1999-2015 Marktplaats.nl. Alle rechten voorbehouden.
</copyright>
<openSearch:totalResults>105976</openSearch:totalResults>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage>100</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
<image>
<title>Marktplaats.nl</title>
<link>http://www.marktplaats.nl</link>
<url>//statisch.marktplaats.com/images/logo.gif</url>
</image>
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Aangeboden: BMW 3-Serie 2.0 328I AUT 2012 Zwart ]]>
</title>
<link>
http://auto.marktplaats.nl/bmw/904347333-bmw-3-serie-2-0-328i-aut-2012-zwart.html
</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://i.marktplaats.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/JDkAAOSwPYZU8XtY/$_82.JPG" align="absmiddle" border="0"> - Prijs: € 29.950,00 - Datum: Vandaag - Bmw 3 Serie Sedan 328ia High Execut Innovation Edit 4d 180kw Perfecte auto veel opties Inclusief zomer winter banden Vaste prijs 29 950
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>za, 28 feb 2015 14:04:56</pubDate>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.marktplaats.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/JDkAAOSwPYZU8XtY/$_82.JPG" type="image/jpeg"/>
<media:content url="http://i.marktplaats.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/JDkAAOSwPYZU8XtY/$_82.JPG" type="image/jpeg"/>
<geo:lat>51.4385</geo:lat>
<geo:long>5.4742</geo:long>
</item>
<item>
```

What i want is to sort the output on the key **pubDate** .
I allready put the output in a PHP array with this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xml_array = (array) $xml;
```

But for now i want to sort the array on the **pubDate**, how can i do that? Output the newest first.

This is the VAR_DUMP

```
Array
```

(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

```
[channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => Marktplaats.nl -  Gevonden resultaten met de zoekterm 'volkswagen or nissan or audi or seat or kia or toyota or peugeot or volvo or bmw or chrysler or mini or citroen or hyundai or mercedes or mazda or alfa or jeep or daewoo or honda or jaguar or mitsubishi or rover or saab or skoda or suzuki or smart'
        [link] => http://www.marktplaats.nl
        [description] => Marktplaats.nl - Gevonden resultaten met de zoekterm 'volkswagen or nissan or audi or seat or kia or toyota or peugeot or volvo or bmw or chrysler or mini or citroen or hyundai or mercedes or mazda or alfa or jeep or daewoo or honda or jaguar or mitsubishi or rover or saab or skoda or suzuki or smart'. Kopen en verkopen van tweedehands of nieuwe producten en van diensten doet u op Marktplaats.nl, de advertentiesite van Nederland. Marktplaats.nl is een compleet overzicht van vraag en aanbod.
        [language] => nl
        [copyright] => Copyright (C) 1999-2015 Marktplaats.nl. Alle rechten voorbehouden.
        [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [title] => Marktplaats.nl
                [link] => http://www.marktplaats.nl
                [url] => //statisch.marktplaats.com/images/logo.gif
            )

        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://auto.marktplaats.nl/mini/903961225-mini-mini-cooper-2003-grijs.html
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [pubDate] => vr, 27 feb 2015 12:14:30
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://auto.marktplaats.nl/rover/903951263-rover-200-serie-1-4-i-214-1999-nieuwe-apk-163-000-km.html
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [pubDate] => vr, 27 feb 2015 11:48:45
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://auto.marktplaats.nl/kia/902153232-kia-picanto-cvvt-luxe-x-treme-airco-ecc-leder-velgen-pdc.html
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [pubDate] => zo, 22 feb 2015 07:32:09
                    )
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, please post a valid but shortened snippet of your XML directly into your question. Future users with the same question can then profit from your work (the link you posted may be outdated or not to open). Plus, please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy problem because of several issues. This works. It requires php >= 5.3.0.

This may still choke depending on how the site presents the months [3,5,6,7,10], since dutch uses [different abbreviations](http://library.princeton.edu/departments/tsd/katmandu/reference/months.html#dutch) for these.

```
$url = 'http://kopen.marktplaats.nl/opensearch.php?s=100&q=chrysler&g=91';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL'); //Time strings are in Dutch.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); //PHP will complain if this is not set.

//The comparison function usort() will use
function compare_item_dates($a, $b) {
    $format = 'j F Y G:i:s';
    $a_date = date_create_from_format($format, trim(substr($a->pubDate, 4)));
    //For troubleshooting. Delete the next line in production.
    if (!$a_date) print_r(array($a->pubDate, $a_date, date_get_last_errors())); 
    //End of troubleshooting area
    $b_date = date_create_from_format($format, trim(substr($b->pubDate, 4)));
    if ($a_date == $b_date) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_date > $b_date) ? -1 : 1;
}

//Parse the items into an array
$xml_items = array();
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
    $xml_items[] = $item;

//Sort the items using the comparison function
usort($xml_items, 'compare_item_dates');

//Generate output
print_r($xml_items);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem in this case is: $xml_array['channel']['item'] is NULL the whole time. Do you know why?

Comment: Oke i solved that problem, its no longer NULL any more. But now i have a Array with all ITEM. But i am not sure how to use your code @cpilko

Comment: @KEVIN: This upset me. I blew off this morning's work to create the compete, working example above.

Comment: I was away, i just work again on the project and try your solution. It works!!! Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to create your own array, because the pubDate value is not a date, it contains a string you would have to strip down (vr, zo and so on).
Then you could use array_multisort() to sort through your multidimensional array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php